# Target Machine Actively refused at - Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost:xxx/api/http/routers

Tags: docker, cloud, sitecore

When I am running up.ps1 script while setting up my local to run XM Cloud, I'm getting the below error.

Background: my system got restarted and after that am facing this issue, docker containers are in the exited state, and not able to restart.

Tried fix: I completely deleted all my docker containers and ran up.ps1 script to install containers again and then the script was running fine.

Docker installed: docker for windows and running in windows containers

Error:

```
strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax
Waiting for CM to become available...
Invoke-RestMethod: C:\pathtoxmcloudproject\up.ps1:59:19
Line |
  59 |  …   $status = Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost:xxxx/api/http/routers …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I tried deleting all containers and re-running the up.ps1 script.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this error a few times and found that it can be resolved by using `docker network prune`

You can create a new PowerShell script to do the following and place it at the same level as your `up.ps1` script;

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

./down.ps1

try {
  Write-Host "Performing 'docker network prune'..." -ForegroundColor Green
  docker network prune --force
  if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    Write-Error "Docker network prune, see errors above."
  }
}
finally {
}

./up.ps1
```